# parameter replacement in a string similar to mysql

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a user modifiable string that will have already set data to replace certain patches of text

example

```
dim name1 as string = "John"
dim state as string = "Virginia"
dim idnumb as integer = 122
dim textlist1 as string

textlist1 = "Hello {NAME}, I see you are from {STATE}, and your id number is {ID}."
```

Ideally I would want to replace these tags with the set strings

I am familiar with

```
Replace(textlist1, "{NAME}", name1)
```

my question is: is this the correct way to do this or is there a method more similar to the way we do parameters in MySql

Comment: `Dim helloString AS String = String.Format("Hello {0}, I see you are from {1}, and your id number is {2}.", theName, theState, theID.ToString)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you could use StringBuilder to avoid the reallocation of a new string for every replace.

```
dim name1 as string = "John"
dim state as string = "Virginia"
dim idnumb as integer = 122
dim textlist1 as StringBuilder = new StringBuilder _ 
             ("Hello {NAME}, I see you are from {STATE}, and your id number is {ID}.")
textlist1.Replace("{NAME}", name1)
```

As supposed the StringBuilder approach is not the best for performance related comparisons
This is just a little benchmark executed via LinqPad

```
Sub Main
    dim name1 as string = "John"
    dim state as string = "Virginia"
    dim idnumb as integer = 122
    dim textlist1 as StringBuilder 

    Dim sw = new Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    for i = 0 to 100000
        textlist1 = new StringBuilder("Hello {NAME}, I see you are from {STATE}, and your id number is {ID}.")
        textlist1.Replace("{NAME}", name1)
        textlist1.Replace("{STATE}", state)
        textlist1.Replace("{ID}", idnumb.ToString())
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    sw.Elapsed.Dump("StringBuilder.Replace")

    sw = new Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    for i = 0 to 100000
        Dim test = "Hello {NAME}, I see you are from {STATE}, and your id number is {ID}."
        Dim test2 = test.Replace("{NAME}", name1)
        Dim test3 = test2.Replace("{STATE}", state)
        Dim test4 = test3.Replace("{ID}", idnumb.ToString())
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    sw.Elapsed.Dump("String.Replace")
End Sub

StringBuilder.Replace 
00:00:00.2795878 

String.Replace 
00:00:00.1642420
```

So it seems that the cost to allocate a string builder outweight the cost to use a fixed interned string. Of course the memory fragmentation caused by the immutable string behavior is not easily measurable.

Comment: However a bit of testing should be done here. Surely the StringBuilder avoid the reallocation, but it is not always the faster approach if you do this operation just a couple of times.

Comment: although poor syntax would anything stop you from rewriting the same variable, example test= test.replace ....  or would this be just as bad on fraging